# Customise WebAPI response like Status, Data, message formate

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

How can i customise WebAPI 2 response like status, data, message in JSON format

**Successful request:**

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    /* Application-specific data would go here. */
  },
  "message": null /* Or optional success message */
}
```

**Failed request:**

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "data": null, /* or optional error payload */
  "message": "Error xyz has occurred"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new class like :

```
public class ResponseDto
{
    public string status { get; set; }

    public dynamic data { get; set; }

    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

and then populate the properties with respective values and do :

```
var response = new ResponseDto()
{
    response.status = " ",
    response.data = obj,
    response.message = " "
}
```

and then from the controller method(API),

```
return response;
```

Your JSON formatter will then convert the response object into JSON string.